# In Immutable.js, how can I union 2 collections, but have the new values replace the old ones

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

For example, I have this collection:

```
[ { 
    staticProp: "something",
    changingProp: [ '1', '2' ] }, 
   {
    staticProp: "somethingElse",
    changingProp: []
  } ]
```

And lets say id like to union it with this one:

```
[{
     staticProp: "something",
     changingProp: [ '3' ]
 }]
```

I would the result to be

```
[ { 
    staticProp: "something",
    changingProp: [ '3' ] }, 
   {
    staticProp: "somethingElse",
    changingProp: []
  } ]
```

It seems that Set.union() keeps the *old* version. Any suggestions?

Comment: this is not how union results

Comment: If I use a Set of Records, it almost does what I want it to,  except for accepting incoming changes of properties which I've not specified in the Record